# What song is playing when Kakashi explains the terms of the bell test in episode 2?

Tags: naruto, music

I have heard it in numerous episodes, including *Naruto Shippuden* episode 2 when Kakashi explains the terms of the bell test, and in one of the filler episodes in the war arc where Kakashi and Gai fight 2 of the swordsmen of the mist

YouTube link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HJsqHazKzmc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the very first track of the Shippuden OST. The title of the track is [Shippuden](http://youtu.be/FKmlDX92IeQ), found on OST 1

Comment: thanks. I cannot believe that the song i had been looking for all this time was literally the very first track of shippuden. now i feel dumb

Comment: @rishthefish I’m glad I could help :)